# Saving to BMP file on Windows 10

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to save a plot to a bmp file on Windows 10.  I can do it with the interactive terminals: windows or qt using the GUI.  But I can't figure out how to do it with commands.  Doing this just results in an empty file.

```
gnuplot> set terminal windows

Terminal type is now 'windows'
Options are '0 color solid butt enhanced standalone'
gnuplot> set output "file.bmp"  
gnuplot> plot sin(x)
Closing file.bmp
```

Comment: Which version of gnuplot are you working with? I observe with gnuplot 5.4.1 and Win10 that `terminal windows` with the standard option `standalone` actually crashes my gnuplot. With option `docked layout 1,1`,  I get a plot and an empty BMP file. Do you really need a huge BMP? Why not a much smaller PNG with the same information?

Comment: @Rob the question is *not* about debugging interactive usage, but about programmatic creation of a file. So, according to tag info: on-topic.

Comment: @Rob `set terminal windows; set output "file.bmp"; plot sin(x)`
That's the gnuplot code which should create a .BMP file, but it apparently does not.

Comment: @theozh Those are program commands, not code.

Comment: @theozh I'm using gnuplot 5.4.3. I need a BMP since I'm using an old win32 program that only accepts BMPs.

Comment: @Rob That's a scripting language.
https://sodocumentation.net/gnuplot/topic/4013/using-script-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I start the gnuplot console and `set term windows` and type `plot sin(x)` gnuplot is crashing. This is certainly a bug or something wrong with my system (Win10, gnuplot 5.4.1). I can only plot without crash if I set the terminal option to `docked layout 1,1`. But then, I get an empty BMP file like you got.

Actually, so far I haven't found any gnuplot version starting from 4.4.0 which seems to be able to create a correct BMP output.

So, then my suggestion would be to create a PNG output and convert this to BMP, e.g. via ImageMagick.

- download and unzip the .zip version of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/)
- copy only the file `magick.exe` to your gnuplot working directory (or somewhere else where your system can find it)
- save the script below into the file `SO71415908.gp`
- either in Windows command line type `gnuplot -c SO71415908.gp`, or alternatively, in gnuplot console type `load "SO71415908.gp"`. However, in the latter case I haven't found out how to close the Windows console windows without closing gnuplot.

**Script:**

```
### create a BMP file with gnuplot via help of ImageMagick
reset session
set terminal pngcairo

FILE = "SO71415908"       # filename without extension

set output sprintf("%s.png",FILE)

plot sin(x)

set output      # close the file, necessary or not?

system sprintf('magick %s.png %s.bmp',FILE,FILE)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

Two files: `SO71415908.png` and `SO71415908.bmp`

Comment: Thanks.  I found this bug which would likely do what I need.
https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/665/